# how to read data from sd card and display spinner of another activity in android

Tags: android, storage

I save file in sd card properly but do not retrieve data of sd card text file and display on spinner of another activity.when I click on read button that data display on spinner of another activity
    when I click on read button txt file item display on spinner

**mainactivity.java**

```
btnWriteSDFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Write);
btnWriteSDFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Jour = display.getText().toString();
        // write on SD card file data in the text box
        try {
            File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
            myFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append(display.getText());
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } // onClick
}); // btnWriteSDFile

btnReadSDFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Read);
btnReadSDFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // write on SD card file data in the text box
        try {
            File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(fIn));
            String aDataRow = "";
            String aBuffer = "";
            while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
            }
            display.setText(aBuffer);
            myReader.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Done reading SD 'mysdfile.txt'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }       
});
```

**list.java**

```
Spinner sp1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);
    sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    getFilesnames();        
}
private void getFilesnames() {
    String[] filenames=getApplicationContext().fileList();
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
        list.add(filenames[i]);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> filenameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
    sp1.setAdapter(filenameAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Follow this link *http://www.sitepoint.com/learning-to-parse-xml-data-in-your-android-app* in order to work with XML protocol to read and write data. I thing this will solve your problem.

Comment: read data from sd card text file and display another activity of spinner

Comment: XML work as a text file with a specific structure, so it is easier to read and work with it.

Comment: I know but all text item by default display on each spinner when I click on read button

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: you want to read this data when activity loads ?